# El ciclo for no me funciona

Tags: java, eclipse

Por alguna razón los ciclos for no me funciona en eclipse luna, actualice los jdk pero sigue igual este es el simple código

```
public class main {

public static void main(String[] arg) {
    System.out.println("inicio");
    for(int i = 0; i > 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Numer: " + i);
    }
}}
```

por alguna razón no funciona, es como si no existiera el for, solo me ocurre con eso y es muy raro.

Comment: Porque lo inicializas en 0 y después condicionas que sea mayor a 10?, Deberias iniciarlo con valor "10", o te equivocaste en la condicion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estoy 99% seguro que el problema está en la condición. 
No codeo en java pero creo q la condicion es de permanemcia en el ciclo. Es decir 
    i<10
Cuando llega a 10 no cumple y sale del loop
Saludos

Comment: si gracias, me acabo de dar cuenta :'v voltee los signos

Answer (score 4):

**Tienes una serie de errores que a continuación te menciono**

1. La variable `i` del ciclo  `for` debe ser menor a `10` y tu le estas indicando que es mayor *eso no va a permitir que se ejecute o que inicie el `bucle for`*

Tu código debería quedar así

2. La condición debe ser `<= 10` para que así el número 10 también se imprima, de otro modo si solo pones `< 10` solo va a imprimir hasta el 9

**CÓDIGO FUNCIONAL**

---

```
public class main {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("inicio");
    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Numer: " + i);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

es por la condicion que le pusiste, tu contador i nunca cumple el ser mayor a 10, si quieres iterar 10 veces :

```
for( i = 0; i < 10; i++) { ... }
```

de esta manera se cumple la condicion 10 veces